# Perl: Get minimum distance value from multi hash using List::Util

Tags: perl, hash

i would like to get the smallest distance to a "snaffle" from the following hash:

```
$VAR1 = {
        '0' => {
                 'y' => '7012',
                 'snaffle' => {
                                '5' => {
                                         'y' => '3856',
                                         'x' => '875',
                                         'id' => '5',
                                         'distance' => 9734
                                       },
                                '6' => {
                                         'x' => '10517',
                                         'id' => '6',
                                         'distance' => 510,
                                         'y' => '6741'
                                       },
                                '4' => {
                                         'y' => '5291',
                                         'id' => '4',
                                         'x' => '11331',
                                         'target' => 'true',
                                         'distance' => 2125
                                       },
                                '8' => {
                                         'x' => '11709',
                                         'id' => '8',
                                         'distance' => 2236,
                                         'y' => '5475'
                                       },
                                '7' => {
                                         'distance' => 8485,
                                         'x' => '4591',
                                         'id' => '7',
                                         'y' => '544'
                                       }
                              },
                 'x' => '10084',
                 'distance2mybase' => 10598,
                 'distance2enemybase' => 6755,
                 'type' => 'WIZARD',
                 'id' => '0',
                 'state' => 0
               },
```

It is filled early:

```
# game loop
while (1) {
chomp(my $entities = <STDIN>); # number of entities still in game
for my $i (0..$entities-1) {
    chomp($tokens=<STDIN>);
    my ($entity_id, $entity_type, $x, $y, $vx, $vy, $state) = split(/ /,$tokens);
    my $type;

    if ($entity_type eq "WIZARD") {
        $type = "wizard";
    }
    if ($entity_type eq "OPPONENT_WIZARD") {
        $type = "enemy";
    }
    if ($entity_type eq "SNAFFLE") {
        $type = "snaffle";            
    }
    if ($entity_type eq "BLUDGER") {
        $type = "bludger";            
    }

    $entity{$type}{$entity_id}{x} = $x;
    $entity{$type}{$entity_id}{y} = $y;
    $entity{$type}{$entity_id}{state} = $state;
    $entity{$type}{$entity_id}{id} = $entity_id;
    $entity{$type}{$entity_id}{type} = $entity_type;
    $entity{$type}{$entity_id}{distance2mybase} = &getdistance($entity{$type}{$entity_id}{x},$entity{$type}{$entity_id}{y},$mybase_x,$mybase_y);
    $entity{$type}{$entity_id}{distance2enemybase} = &getdistance($entity{$type}{$entity_id}{x},$entity{$type}{$entity_id}{y},$enemybase_x,$enemybase_y);
}

foreach my $wizard_id (sort keys %{ $entity{'wizard'} }) {
    foreach my $snaffle_id (sort keys %{ $entity{'snaffle'} }) {
        $entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{id} = $snaffle_id;
        $entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{x} = $entity{'snaffle'}{$snaffle_id}{x};
        $entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{y} = $entity{'snaffle'}{$snaffle_id}{y};
        $entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{distance} = &getdistance($entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{x},$entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{y},$entity{'snaffle'}{$snaffle_id}{x},$entity{'snaffle'}{$snaffle_id}{y});
    }
&action($wizard_id,"sweep","up");
}
```

I tried List::Util::min, but i think im searching too deep, because as you can see in the output, it targets the wrong snaffle. (6 distance is lower then 4, which is the current target)

How can i find the overall minimum distance from all snaffles? (in case you wonder, its a codingame(.com))

```
sub snafflecheck {
my $wizard_id = shift;
my $wizard_x = shift;
my $wizard_y = shift;
if ($entity{'snaffle'}) {
    foreach my $snaffle_id (sort keys %{ $entity{'snaffle'} }) {
        my $snaffle_x = $entity{'snaffle'}{$snaffle_id}{x};
        my $snaffle_y = $entity{'snaffle'}{$snaffle_id}{y};

        my $distance2snaffle = &getdistance($wizard_x,$wizard_y,$snaffle_x,$snaffle_y);
        my $nearest = min $entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{distance};


        if ($distance2snaffle) {
            if ($distance2snaffle == $nearest) {
                $entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{target} = "true";
                return("true",$entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{id},$entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{x},$entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{y},$distance2snaffle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The min of one value (`min $entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{distance}`) is that value (`$entity{'wizard'}{$wizard_id}{snaffle}{$snaffle_id}{distance}`).

Comment: These are your distances `my @dist = map { $_->{distance} } (values %{$entity->{0}{snaffle}});`  However, `List::Util::min` won't say what key the minimum belongs to.

Comment: Re "*the smallest distance to a "snaffle"*", What does this mean?? i'm trying to figure it out from your code, but your code appears to expect a completely different data structure than the one you posted!

Comment: Thanks for your input, i added more code.

Comment: Pilling on code that doesn't relate to the data structure you posted is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first extract the reference to the `snaffle` hash to make things tidier. Then you can just use `map` to extract the `distance` field of each hash element and `min` to find the smallest of them.

If you want to know the *snaffle with the smallest distance* then
I suggest that you install [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) and use its `min_by` operator

This code shows both operations

*The hash is identical to your own, but expressed more compactly using `Data::Dump` instead*

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use List::Util 'min';
use List::UtilsBy 'min_by';

my %data = (
    "0" => {
        distance2enemybase => 6755,
        distance2mybase    => 10598,
        id                 => 0,
        snaffle            => {
            4 => { distance => 2125, id => 4, target => "true", x => 11331, y => 5291 },
            5 => { distance => 9734, id => 5, x      => 875,    y => 3856 },
            6 => { distance => 510,  id => 6, x      => 10517,  y => 6741 },
            7 => { distance => 8485, id => 7, x      => 4591,   y => 544 },
            8 => { distance => 2236, id => 8, x      => 11709,  y => 5475 },
        },
        state => 0,
        type  => "WIZARD",
        x     => 10084,
        y     => 7012,
    },
);

my $snaffles = $data{0}{snaffle};

my $min_distance = min map { $snaffles->{$_}{distance} } keys %$snaffles;
# OR
my $min_distance = min map { $_->{distance} } values %$snaffles;


my $closest_snaffle = min_by { $snaffles->{$_}{distance} } keys %$snaffles;

say "\$min_distance = $min_distance";
say "\$closest_snaffle = $closest_snaffle";
```

#### output

```
$min_distance = 510
$closest_snaffle = 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the shown data, this is the list of all values for key `distance`

```
my @dist = map { $_->{distance} } values %{$entity->{0}{snaffle}};
```

However, getting the minimum value doesn't reveal its key.

One way of finding the key for which the value of `distance` is smallest

```
use List::Util 'reduce';

my $snaff = $entity->{0}{snaffle};

my $min_dist = reduce { 
    $snaff->{$a}{distance} < $snaff->{$b}{distance} ? $a : $b 
} keys %$snaff;

print "Minimal distance: $snaff->{$min_dist}{distance} for key $min_dist\n";
```

To have more control you can instead iterate over `%$snaff` using [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html).

You can also [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) the extracted `$snaff` by `distance` value, if you'd like to have them all.